# Android read PNG steganography

Tags: java, android, png

I am using bitmap factory to read a png uri and get the associated bitmap.  The problem I am facing is when the uri is over 64 MP, I get an out of memory error.  I read elsewhere that I can get a scaled bitmap, however this is not suitable for my purposes, because it is a steganography app, so scaling the png would destroy the hidden data.  is there a way to read just a portion of the png uri at a time?  I figure if I can read a few thousand pixels at a time, then I wont hit the memory constraints.  perhaps another solution would be to utilize the hard drive space?  if there was a way to convert to a bmp using some file based api, then I could just read the generated bmp file sequentially.  Are there any options here?  Or will I have to resort to simply giving a "file too large, choose another file" message to the user?

The following link describes the same issue, but as I said, the scaling solution provided will not work for my purposes.

[out of memory](https://android.jlelse.eu/loading-large-bitmaps-efficiently-in-android-66826cd4ad53)

Comment: You better find out how the pixels are stored in the png file. Then you can just read the file in chuncks, update the pixels in the chuncks and write all to a new file.

Comment: Stored using lsb of each ARGB byte (4 bits stored in 4 bytes).  I was hoping I wouldn't have to implement a png decompression algorithm.